# RLMException: 'Primary key property 'serial' does not exist on object 'Book' Migrating to Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm running into this issue with Realm on iOS using Swift 4 compilation, where on startup the app crashes with the following message

```
RLMException', reason: 'Primary key property 'serial' does not exist on object 'Book''
```

I saw similar error messages, but not the same one.
This is what my object looks like

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Book: Object {
    dynamic var serial: String = ""
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var pages: Int = 0
    dynamic var genre: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "serial"
    }
}
```

When I checked the default.realm file through the Realm Browser app, I noticed that the entries only have a # (0,1,2) and no data in it.  If I comment out the primary key, it runs, but nothing is stored in Realm for this object. Can't figure out why it's crashing!

Comment: That code wasn't even working Realm code in Swift 3. You needed to mark Realm properties as dynamic in Swift 3 (not sure about previous versions though), the only change in Swift 4 is that you also have to add the `@objc` attribute.

Comment: good catch, purpose of the question/answer was to highlight the @objc being necessary. question edited.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In Realm, the properties of your model have to have the `@objc dynamic var` attribute, that is what I was missing.

From [Realm website](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models):

> Realm model properties must have the `@objc dynamic var` attribute to become accessors for the underlying database data. Note that if the class is declared as `@objcMembers` (Swift 4 or later), the individual properties can just be declared as `dynamic var`.

Answer (score 60):

Although it doesn't necessarily about migration, there's an issue with iOS 13 and Xcode 11 which may cause this problem. All String properties of Realm classes with a default `String` value set are disregarded somehow.
You can fix this by updating to the latest version (currently 3.20.0) and than on Xcode: Product -> Clean Build Folder.

If you're using cocoa-pods, do this:

Open your project's Podfile, and replace RealmSwift line with:

```
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.20.0'
```

Then, open terminal on the project's folder and:

```
pod repo update
pod install
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My app was crashing only on iOS 13 and I did not understand the reason why.

Comment: Same issue here... only on iOS 13

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. The only change I had made was to update Xcode and it caused this crash.  My Realm db looked fine when I opened it in Realm Studio, the realm code hadn't changed in forever so it was baffling.

Answer (score 9):

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Book: Object {
   @objc dynamic var id : Int = 0
   @objc dynamic var serial: String = ""
   @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
   @objc dynamic var pages: Int = 0
   @objc dynamic var genre: String = ""

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, however mine was due to the fact that I was converting a non-Realm class to a Realm class.  I originally had:

```
@objc dynamic let customerId: String
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "customerId"
}
```

...but I needed to change the "let" to a "var":

```
@objc dynamic var customerId: String
override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "customerId"
}
```

It wasn't obvious from the error message that that was the problem, but it instantly fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In same this issue in my case is born I forget write `@objc` in param

**my case** error is

```
dynamic var yourValue: String!
```

**fix by**

```
 @objc dynamic var yourValue: String!
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Realm in Pod file with the new version of Realm like :

From

```
pod 'RealmSwift', '~> 3.11.0'
```

TO

```
 pod 'Realm',  git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true


  pod 'RealmSwift', git: 'https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git', branch: 'master', submodules: true
```

make sure about the all fields define like :

```
 @objc dynamic var myID: String!
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, adding @objMembers on top of the class name fixed it

Ex:

```
@objcMembers
internal final class Recipient: Mappable {
dynamic var transferID: String = ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Computed primary keys do not work (like in hijacked id from a an embedded object see code below):

```
@objc dynamic var id: String
{
    guard let id = header?.id else {
        assertionFailure()
        return ""
    }
    return id
}
```

So you have to make a plain `@Persisted var id: String`
set in in init()s of all ilk and presumably keep track of the one2one dependency (header in my case that has the key) with didSet. Realm object observer [realm swift: how could I trap on object being invalidated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71840097/realm-swift-how-could-i-trap-on-object-being-invalidated). might be of some use? didSet should suffice me thinks.