# realm swift: how could I trap on object being invalidated?

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm

I'm attempting to add a watcher for isInvalidated on an object of interest like so:

```
cancellable = images.publisher(for: \.isInvalidated, options: [.new])
            .sink { newValue in
                print("property changed")
            }
```

which yields

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "property descriptor for (extension in RealmSwift):__C.RealmSwiftEmbeddedObject.isInvalidated : Swift.Bool", referenced from:
      l_keypath in ContentCardView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

at link time.
How would I add a [programmatic] watchpoint for invalidation of an object in realm?

PS a simpler way out via lldb does not work either

```
(lldb) watch images.isInvalidated
error: command 'watchpoint' did not recognize 'images .isInvalidated' as valid (subcommand might be invalid).
(lldb) watch images.invalidated
error: command 'watchpoint' did not recognize 'images .invalidated' as valid (subcommand might be invalid).
(lldb) wa s v images.invalidated
error: "invalidated" is not a member of "(Foo) images"
(lldb) wa s v images.isInvalidated
error: "isInvalidated" is not a member of "(Foo) images"
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague - what is `images`, an array? If so that's the issue. Have you considered using a Realm object observer so you can take action when an object is deleted, inserted or modified?

Comment: (being a mongonoob) I was not aware of this functionality, but (Thanks to you!) it seems that it's what I needed indeed. images is an instance of a class derived from EmbeddedObject

Comment: Glad to help. Keep in mind that Embedded Objects cannot exist alone - that are not independently managed - they must be part of (e.g. a property) another object. Calling it `images` (plural) leads us to believe it's multiple image objects which could for example, be part of a List property of another object. If that's not what it is/they are, there may be other issues as well.

Comment: That's legacy naming from a developer for who[m] English is not a first language, I have bigger fish to fry at the moment than renaming legacy vars. But thanks.

Comment: Actually @objcMembers class ExploreImages: EmbeddedObject, Codable {
    Persisted var coverImage: String
    Persisted var thumbnail: String
    Persisted var icon: String so the developer might've been onto something, technically 3 images of different resolution are images